# How to convert gif in mp4 video with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

Is there a way to convert a `.gif` uploaded image into `.mp4` with only Nodejs?  How do I integrate that with a MEAN app? I want to be able to store the converted .mp4 file to S3.

Using : https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg-extended but get error : `Invalid Input`

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
       s3: s3,
       bucket: 'mybucket',
       key: function (req, file, cb) {
        var extension = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();
            if(extension == "gif"){
                console.log(file);
                var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: file })
                  .usingPreset('podcast')
                  .saveToFile('/path/to/your_target.m4v', function(stdout, stderr) {
                    console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
                  });
            }
            else{
                cb(null, file.originalname);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this library. it's a wrapper for ffmpeg executable, so you'll need to have it as well.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg-extended

This thread will be helpful as well,

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/36060167-converting-gif-buffer-to-mp4-buffer-without-writing-to-file-first

Comment: Thanks. How do I implement it on an uploaded file. I edited the question. Please have a look. With the above code I get `Invalid Input`.

Comment: How else do I reference the uploaded `file`? Why is it saying `invalid input` for the `file`? `  var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: file })` is the line where Im getting the error

Comment: did you try hard coding the path ?

Comment: How to do that in an uploaded file? I also tried using it with hardcoded path but it fails too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176748/unable-to-convert-files-with-fluent-ffmpeg and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176898/how-to-convert-files-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score -1):

```
var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');
var ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
var ffprobePath = require('@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe').path;
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobePath);
export let UPLOAD_PATH = 'public';
// video : any live video url or any video path from your local storage
    public createGif (video, fileName){
        ffmpeg(video)
        .setStartTime('00:00:03')
        .setDuration('10')
        .output(`${UPLOAD_PATH}/${fileName}`)
        .on('end', function(err) {
          if(!err) { console.log('conversion Done') }
        })
        .on('error', function(err){
          console.log('error: ', err)
      }).run()
    }
```

You can use "ffmpeg" npm package to convert video to gif
complete code written over here

Comment: How can you be importing two libraries of the same name?