# Unable to convert files with fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I installed fluent-ffmpeg with `npm install fluent-ffmpeg` and verified its present in the node-modules. There is no error if I include it in the server `var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');` But when I use it to convert a `.gif` file in the directory to `.mp4` it throws an error : `Error: Cannot find ffmpeg`

My code :

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: '/uploads/myfile.gif' })
  .usingPreset('podcast')
  .saveToFile('/uploads/mynewfile.mp4', function(stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
  });
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to convert the `.gif` to `.mp4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that node-fluent can't find ffmpeg, use `which` to get the path of ffmpeg, and add this line:

```
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath('Path\\to\\ffmpeg');
```